# .get(key) wont give me my value in a Hashmap<Point, Integer>

Tags: java, hashmap, point

I'm a bit new to programming and wanted to try making a more difficult box style 2d game **for learning** then my previous game. Alas I'm still new so **please dumb down your answer** if possible.

I've been toying around with hash maps for a few hours now and cant seem to figure out why feeding java my key wont give me its value back.

```
package main;

public class Point {

  private int x;
  private int y;

  public Point(int x, int y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }

  public int getX() {
    return this.x;
  }
  public int getY() {
    return this.y;
  }
}
```

```
public Map<Point, Integer> Blocks = new HashMap<Point, Integer>();

int x = 0;
int y = 0;

while (active == true) {

  Point Apple = new Point(x, y);
  Blocks.put(Apple, 1);

  if (x <= 800) {
    x += 32;
  } else {
    x = 0;
    y += 32;
  }

  if (y > 600) {
    active = false;
  }
}

MouseX = (Mouse.getX() / 32) * 32;
MouseY = (Mouse.getY() / 32) * 32;
Point rawr = new Point(MouseX, MouseY);

if (Blocks.containsKey(rawr)) {
  y = Blocks.get(rawr);
}
```

I get y = 0 instead of y = 1 as a result. Thanks for any help given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You fail to obey the most fundamental contract of java: the [.equals()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29)/[.hashCode()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29) contract.

You need to override them both in class `Point`. There are many examples here on SO and on the net in general.

Now, why this applies here is because you try and see if the `blocks` map contains a `Point` which you have instantiated. But keys in a `HashMap`, which you use, rely heavily on `.equals()` and `.hashCode()`. It `.contains(x)` if and only if there is one key of the map `k` such that `k.equals(x)`.

For your class:

```
@Override
public int hashCode()
{
    return 31 * x + y;
    // If using Java 7, this can be:
    // returns Objects.hash(x, y);
}

@Override
public boolean equals(final Object o)
{
    // No object instance is equal to null
    if (o == null)
        return false;
    // If the object is the same, this is true
    if (this == o)
        return true;
    // If not the same object class, false
    if (getClass() != o.getClass())
        return false;

    final Point other = (Point) o; // safe to cast since getClass() == o.getClass()
    return x == other.x && y == other.y; // test instance member equality
}
```

Comment: Bassically, if you do not override them, they `Map` (and other containers) will match only the **same instance**, and not a different instance which represents the same point (same `x` and `y`)

Comment: Via testing I figured it may of been the instances varying the hash code that led to my programs downfall but I didn't know how to approach searching for a solution or if that was really even the case. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. In estimation, how hard do you believe creating the solution will be for somebody whose pretty new? Or is it rather basic stuff.

Comment: @Shawn it is "basic" stuff but sometimes tricky to get right. See my edit for an example for your class.

Comment: In fact, the problem is NOT that he has failed to obey the contract.  The REAL problem is that he has the wrong kind of equality semantics.

Answer (score 0):

The root problem is that your `Point` key has the wrong semantics for its `equals` method.  You are using the `equals` method inherited from from `Object`, and *that* method says that two objects are "equal" if-and-only-if they are the same object.

So suppose you create (say) a point instance as `new Point(1,1)` and use it as the key to add an entry to the hash table.  Then when you want to do a lookup of the point at `(1,1)`, you create a second point instance (with  `new Point(1,1)`) ... and call `get(...)`.  But this new point is a *different* point object (`p1.equals(p2)` is `false'!)... so the lookup fails.

The solution is to override `equals` in your `Point` class so that two `Point` objects are "equal" if they have the same `x` and `y` attributes.  You *then* need to override `hashcode` so the `equals()` / `hashcode()` contract is met.

Here's an example:

```
//
// The fields are 'final' because we want make it clear that a Point
// is immutable.  The class itself is 'final' to simplify the problem of
// testing for equality.  (Equality between an instance of a class and 
// an instance of a subclass can be problematic. If the subclass overrides
// the `equals` method you get in problems with the requirement that equality
// is symmetric; i.e. ensuring that 't.equals(st) == st.equals(t)'.  Making 
// Pint `final` removes that potential issue.)
//
public final class Point {

  private final int x;
  private final int y;

  public Point(int x, int y) { this.x = x; this.y = y; }

  public int getX() { return this.x; }
  public int getY() { return this.y; }

  public boolean equals(Object other) {
    if (this == other) {
      return true;
    }
    if (!(other instanceof Point)) {
      return false;
    }
    Point point = (Point) other;
    return this.x = point.x && this.y == point.y;
  }

  public int hashcode() {
    return this.x + 31 * this.y;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for another example, it really helps clarify things for me. I also previously googled this subject before the latter post had an example. The op of the example said it was most likely in somebodies best interest to make the hash code immutable, is that why you used final for your integers?